# Comparing array of custom object using assertJ method containsOnly()

Tags: java, testing, junit, assertj

My custom object looks like following:

```
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class SocialLink {

    private String platform;

    private String link;
}
```

My test code looks like:

```
SocialLink[] arr1 = new SocialLink[] {
        new SocialLink("Facebook", "Facebook Link"),
        new SocialLink("Google", "Google Link")
};
SocialLink[] arr2 = new SocialLink[] {
        new SocialLink("Google", "Google Link"),
        new SocialLink("Facebook", "Facebook Link")
};
assertThat(arr1).containsOnly(arr2);
```

Failure log:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
  <[SocialLink(platform=Facebook, link=Facebook Link),
    SocialLink(platform=Google, link=Google Link)]>
to contain only:
  <[SocialLink(platform=Google, link=Google Link),
    SocialLink(platform=Facebook, link=Facebook Link)]>
elements not found:
  <[SocialLink(platform=Google, link=Google Link),
    SocialLink(platform=Facebook, link=Facebook Link)]>
and elements not expected:
  <[SocialLink(platform=Facebook, link=Facebook Link),
    SocialLink(platform=Google, link=Google Link)]>
```

**containsOnly()** method works fine with an array of string but why doesn't it working for custom object array?

Comment: Did you override the `equal()` and `hashCode()` methods of `SocialLink`? Maybe you need `containsInAnyOrder`

Comment: @MincongHuang No. `SocialLink` class looks like exactly what I have given here. I am expecting assertJ will match field by field automatically as it does when we use `isEqualToComparingFieldByField()` method

Comment: @MincongHuang Yes, overriding equal() and hashCode() it worked. I usually I don't want to override those in model classes as it has pros and cons. Thanks.

Comment: You can specify a comparator for elements with `usingElementComparator` if you don't want to override equals.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want or can't override equals then an option to try would be calling `usingRecursiveComparison` or more fine grained alternatives `ignoringOverriddenEqualsForTypes`, `ignoringOverriddenEqualsForFields` or `ignoringOverriddenEqualsForFieldsMatchingRegexes`

```
 assertThat(links1).usingRecursiveComparison()
                   .ignoringCollectionOrder() 
                   .isEqualTo(expectedLinks);
```

Note that the recursive comparison only provides `isEqualTo` assertion at the moment.

See https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison for details.